# ExtJs - Is it possible to have a tree with input fields in a leaf?

Tags: extjs, checkbox, treeview, textfield

I'd like to expose the settings of my app to the user in a tree view. There should not be a problem to display. The setting and its value can be displayed as a text node.

Now comes the hard part. I'd like the settings to be editable. When I click on a setting, I want it to be editable, with different fields :

- Display a checkbox
- Display a textfield to change the value
- Display a combobox with valid values

Is there a possiblity to achieve something similar, or do I imagine the impossible here ?
I saw an [example which checkboxes](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#check-tree), but I'm not sure if it is possible to mix fields.

I'm not asking for code, I just liked to know if someone already tried something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what Ext.grid.property.Grid does (minus the checkbox). Since a tree is a gridpanel with a special column, you should be able to mix the two. I would start by porting the propertygrid.

Answer (score -1):

I never tried the the combobox-part, but everything else is definitely possible

[image: Treeview with checkboxes and editable textfields]

All the fields are editable with with the celledit plugin

Hope this helps and I understood your question correctly